# HttpWebRequest POST - Login Token

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, httpwebrequest

This is my httpwebrequest postdata:

`"token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&bmlUrl=&bmlType=&bmlDomain=&bmlFolder=&dest=&response=&challenge=&email=" & username & "&password=" & password`

*i'm doing this in vb.net*

How can i get this token? I can't login without it, page returns bad request (400).

**I'm trying to login to AdFly.**

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what your issue is. Do you ask how you should get token value from the AdFly to send them back? Or do you ask how to parse it on the server side (if you use some proxy server). Also typically some code poiniting out where exactly you have issues is very helpful to get a good answer.

Comment: I think i was pretty clear, i want to login to AdFly with httpwebrequest with postData code above. To login i need token which i don't know how to get so i'm asking here for help - **how to get login token?**

Comment: Authentication tokens are always somewhere in login page html.

Comment: Adfly only requires email and password. No token. Look here: https://login.adf.ly/login?d

Comment: Variables usually are also exchanged in to headers (cookies). Check them with a watch